# One-to-many and one-to-one relationships between the same two models

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have a `Player` class and each player owns X amount of `Character` instances:

```
class Player(Model):
    characters = relationship('Character', back_populates='owner')

class Character(Model):
    owner = relationship('Player', back_populates='characters')
    owner_id = Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
```

But on top of this, each has a single character which he's currently controlling. This means that every player has multiple characters they own, but only one of which is active, so I need to be able to keep that in a separate value or so.

How would I add the one-to-one relationship next to this existing one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Add one more boolean column name as active, Which will have a value as True or False.

 And make player and active id to be unique with character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently SQLAlchemy has an `uselist=False` option for `relationship()`, I just ended up using it...

```
class Player(Model):
    character = relationship('Character', uselist=False, back_populates='owner')
    characters = relationship('Character', back_populates='owner')

class Character(Model):
    owner = relationship('Player', back_populates='characters')
    owner_id = Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you add one more column to Player table, to keep players current character. You can change it when you need:

```
class Player(Model):
    characters = relationship('Character', back_populates='owner')
    current_character = Column('character_id', Integer, ForeignKey('character.id'))
    def refresh(self, id):
        c_id = session.query(Character).filter(character.id == id)
        if c_id:
            self.current_character = c_id.id
            session.add(self)
```